# How can I change the background color of the selected menuItem in shinydashboard?

Tags: css, r, shinydashboard

I have included a simple example code. If I selected `Widgets`, the background color of the `Widgets` menuItem should change.

The code is as follows

```
    ## Only run this example in interactive R sessions
if (interactive()) {

  ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Simple tabs"),
    dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(

        menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
        menuItem("Widgets", tabName = "widgets", icon = icon("th"))
      )

    ),
    dashboardBody(
      tabItems(
        tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
                h2("Dashboard tab content")
        ),
        tabItem(tabName = "widgets",
                h2("Widgets tab content")
        )
      )
    )
  )

  server <- function(input, output, session) {


    }


}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Should I add a CSS tag? Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try the toggleClass function to toggle between CSS classes.
Usage and examples can be found [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/shinyjs/man/classFuncs.html#heading-1).

Comment: Hi, @Simpling. Thank you for sharing the resource. How can I apply that to menuItem? Elements like ` actionButton` have an inputId that can be tracked. So basically, if I select the `Dashboard` menuItem , the menuItem's tab color should change.